Adjust vertical spacing in Flow in QML
I can adjust the horizontal spacing of elements inside a flow in QML,
But i cannot adjust vertical spacing between elements
Suggest a way to adjust vertical spacing in QML
Vertical spacing in FLOW in QML
Is it possible to adjust vertical spacing?
CODE:
   Flow {
        id: FlowId
        width: 540
        spacing: 0
        Repeater {
            id: repeaterForButtons
            model:Model

            Button {
              id: rutton

              contentItem: Text {
                 text: text
                 font.pixelSize: 14
                 opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                 horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                 verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                 elide: Text.ElideRight
               }

                background: Rectangle {
                  opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.3
                  border.width: 1
                  radius: 2
               }
     }

OUTPUT:


Your CustomButton.width is > Flow.width ?

No its type error, Its not 100, its 540 @Stephen Quan

You're not setting a size for your background object. Try setting implicitWidth and implicitHeight.

Adding the below in the Rectangle object solves the issue
        background: Rectangle {
          ***anchors.fill: parent***
          opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.3
          border.width: 1
          radius: 2
       }


When I run a version of your code, I do not see the gap:
    Flow {
        width: 540
        spacing: 0
        Repeater {
            model: "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".split(/ /)
            delegate: Button {           
                width: 180
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }

You can Try it Online

Edited the question with more information - kindly check @Stephen Quan

@JeyanthInba the flow renders correctly, which means the problem is related with your custombutton

Added button code snippet @Moia

If you want to adjust vertical gap in Flow, you can wrap your Button by Item:
Item {
    height: yourButton.height + gapYouWantToSet
    width: yourButton.width

    Button {
        id: yourButton
    }
}

